# Android : Restrict app update for customers using older versions of Android

Tags: android, cordova

My Cordova project is going though a major enhancement at the moment.
And the app is already live and has a very good customer base from Android 2.3 to 5.1.

But after the enhancement the app will not be able to support Android versions below 4.1

I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the users from updating their app if the the user's android version is below 4.1

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the case when you adopt your manifest and set the minsdk to your desired version. Then older devices are excluded.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks for the reply. Does that mean if I set the minsdk to 4.1 for my next app release(update), then the people with lower android version and the my app is already installed in their device will not be able to update the app and so that they can continue with existing features of the app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But not to 4.1 but to the API level so 16 in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to restrict the users from updating their app if the the user's android version is below 4.1

You just need to set `android:minSdk="16"` and users with lower versions of Android will not get update offer. They also will no longer be able to find your app in Google Play (using Play app on the device) as store filters all incompatible apps out due to unmet requirement(s). But they will be able to use currently installed version of your app.